# ML.Net 'TransformsCatalog' does not contain a definition for 'LoadRawImageBytes'

Tags: ml.net

I am trying to implement one of the examples of ML.Net. The project in the example is targeting .Net core 2.1 and I am building the my project in .NET 4.7 Framework.
The issue I have is that the line below does not compile

*mlContext.Transforms.LoadRawImageBytes(.....etc)*

and the error I am getting is

Error   CS1061  'TransformsCatalog' does not contain a definition for 'LoadRawImageBytes' and no accessible extension method 'LoadRawImageBytes' accepting a first argument of type 'TransformsCatalog' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
I have looked and LoadRawImageBytes is supposed to be part of the methods, but it is not recognized.
I am using ML.Net 1.4.0 Nuget package.
Any ideas?
Many thanks

Comment: You probably need to also install the Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics NuGet package -  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics/

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had installed it. It is working.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's now working :)

Answer (score 3):

Install Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics NuGet package
nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics